# Changing developer name for iOS enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, xcode

We're creating an iOS app for enterprise distribution. Most apps, when seen in iTunes, show the name and the developer name (or company, listed under 'Artist' in Info) below the icon. Currently out app shows the icon and name, but no developer name.

In Xcode, you can change the app name, etc. in the target settings, but I can't find any place to change developer name, nor can I find any good references on how this works. So is it possible to change the name from within Xcode, and if so how, or is there another way it must be done?

Answer (score 0):

The **Seller Information** is set up in **iTunes Connect** when are you first publishing your app.

> *The first time you add an app is your only chance to set a company name distinct from your legal entity name.*

If you have enrolled as an individual, the company name is the same as your legal entity name

[iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is only for apps published through the App Store, and we're doing enterprise. Either way, the name isn't appearing at all, even though (I think) the legal name is set. Either way, thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this information in your manifest plist?

Comment: App name and other details, yes, but I haven't been able to find anything about dev name.

Comment: I see artistName as one of the keys.  Odds are, if you put your company name in there, it will display as Artist. It probably uses one of the other fields for developer name, like artistName does.  A little trial and error should figure it out.